# Hash Map Implementation using linked list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, hashmap

I wanted to ask that can i implement a Hash Map using singly linked list? (i am going to resolve collisions by quadratic probing)
P.S I am new to python.

Comment: Yes, you can implement a hash map using a singly-linked list. Do you have a question about your attempt to do so?

Comment: hello, this is language independent question. irrespective it's python, go, java etc. You should look how data structures work in order to implement.

Comment: @chepner oh no, ig i was just sort of confused, so just wanted to confirm. Thanks tho!